# Python startswith function: printing non partially matched lines

Tags: python, windows, python-2.x, prefix, startswith

Hi I want to use the [startswith](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=startswith#str.startswith) function to print out the lines in `fileY.txt` which are **NOT** partially matched with the lines in `fileX.txt`

In the script below I use `fileX.txt` and `fileY.txt` as lists. I then search `fileX.txt` for a partial match with `fileY.txt` using the [startswith](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=startswith#str.startswith) function.

Next I attempt to print the lines which are **NOT** partially matched between `fileX.txt` and `fileY.txt`. However the script only prints the last line in `fileY.txt`

Any help will suggestions will be appreciated (I don't mind if I have to use a helper app like sed for example)

**Source:**

```
#load lines from file into lists
lines1 = [line1.rstrip('\n') for line1 in open('fileX.txt')]
lines2 = [line2.rstrip('\n') for line2 in open('fileY.txt')]

#set lines
set_of_lines1 = set(lines1)
set_of_lines2 = set(lines2)

#set common
common = set_of_lines1 & set_of_lines2

#return lines which partially match as variable e
[e for e in lines1 if e.startswith(tuple(lines2))]

#minus partially matched lines from fileY.txt
difference = set_of_lines2 - e

#print the non matching lines
for color in difference:
   print 'The color prefix ' + color + ' does not exist in the list'
```

**fileX.txt:**

```
blue
green
red
```

**fileY.txt:**

```
blu
gre
re
whi
oran
```

**What I want:**

```
C:\Users\Foo\Bar\Python\Test\>C:\python27\python Test.py
The color prefix whi does not exist in the list
The color prefix oran does not exist in the list

Press any key to continue . . .
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first problem is with this line:

```
[e for e in lines1 if e.startswith(tuple(lines2))]
```

It constructs a list of partial matches, *and then throws it away*. All you retain is the value of `e` which has leaked out of the list comprehension (and in Python 3 would give you an undefined value error). You need:

```
partial_match = [e for e in lines1 if e.startswith(tuple(lines2))]
```

which brings us to the second problem. If you print out `partial_match`, you will see that it contains `['blue', 'green', 'red']` and I think you are expecting it to contain `['blu', 'gre', 're']`, because you are trying to do a set difference between it and `set(['blu', 're', 'gre', 'whi', 'oran'])`.

Since your problems revolve around the list comprehension I suggest you unwind it into a loop where you can print out intermediate values so you can see what is going on and get the logic right. If you really want a one-liner you can always rewrite it later.

Like this:

```
matches = []
for prefix in lines2:
    for colour in lines1:
        if colour.startswith(prefix):
            matches.append(prefix)
```

`matches` will now contain `['blu', 'gre', 're']`. Now report on the prefixes that are not matches.

```
for nomatch in set(lines2) - set(matches):
    print "The color prefix %r does not exist in the list" % nomatch
```

This will give you the output:

```
The color prefix 'whi' does not exist in the list
The color prefix 'oran' does not exist in the list
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation it's helping me understand the general logic.

Comment: The fundamental problem you had was this clever bit of code: `e.startswith(tuple(lines2)`. That tells you if something in `lines1` gets matched, but *it doesn't tell you which prefix it matched, only that one of them did.* Which would be okay, were it not for the fact that you're interested in which prefix matched.